# pip - Cannot fetch index base URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, easy-install

I am trying to install beautiful soup though SSH, and am running

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

and it give me this error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4': Permission denied

Command /usr/bin/python -c "import 
setuptools;__file__='/home/spefon/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-cyQHO1-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```

Why is this happening? I can install lxml with pip just fine, so is it something about beautiful soup?

Thanks

Comment: it's case sensitive: `pip install BeautifulSoup4`

Comment: @Cfreak now I get new error see above

Comment: is that the full error? There should be a longer traceback.

Comment: @Cfreak missed this  `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4': Permission denied` added now

Comment: `Permission denied`. You don't have proper permission to install a package. Either you need to use a virtual environment or you need to use `sudo` to install it.

Comment: @Cfreak okay sudo doesn't work cause I don't have root access, and Virtual environment I have had trouble with, I have it installed in the virtual enviorment but then when I run a program where I call bs4, I get module doesn't exist error?

Comment: You need to ask your administrator to install it or try posting the errors you have with virtual environment. I kinda love Virtual Environment. Perhaps read the documentation of VE, since you need to start the VE

Comment: @DJanssens I don't have access to sudo

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment, install and then run your script? How are you running the script? From the command line?

Comment: @Cfreak Correct from the command line in SSH, when its installed in the virtual envirmoent, I still `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ` right?, nothing changes?

Comment: Did you use the following commands: 'mkvirtualenv mynewenv' followed by 'workon mynewenv' this should normally change your bash window. You need to be working on the VE while installing BS4 and while running the script. http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html helped me a lot.

Comment: @DJanssens I need to be in VE when I run the script didn't know that? What if I wasn't going to always run the script from the command line inside VE, could I run it with CronJobs and it would know to go into the VE?, and ill read those docs you posted thanks

Comment: Creating a virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper is actually like creating a new python environment that you install. You can install libraries in that new environment, but these won't be accessible by your default python environment that's installed on your system. Therefore you will need to issue the 'workon' command, to notify that you use the virtual environment that has those libraries installed and next you can run your scripts like you would normally do.

Comment: You can always install a package into user-site with `pip install --user`